# Jupyter: InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz, decision-tree

I tried to visualize a Decision Tree on Jupyter Notebook (Python version 3.6.10) but was unable to.

```py
from sklearn import tree
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy') 
model=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(trainData,trainLabel)
model.score(trainData,trainLabel)
predicted= model.predict(testData)

from io import StringIO
dot_data = StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz(model, out_file=dot_data) 
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 
Image(graph.create_png())
```

I keep getting "GraphViz's executables not found". Even after checking other threads about the same problem, adding the environment variable, and restarting Jupyter, I still have this problem.

UPDATE 12/13/2020: I was able to fix this problem. This is what I did:

Below the block with my other import statements, I put a block like this:

```py
import os

os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH']+';'+os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX']+r"\Library\bin\graphviz"
```

Comment: Did you install graphviz / dot? did you try to start dot from a command prompt outside of jupyter?

Comment: Yes I did install graphviz. I tried running dot.exe from the regular command prompt, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same issue. This needs some environment variable to set. So what I would suggest is  run the below command

**`conda install python-graphviz`**

instead of

```
pip install graphviz
```

to get these bindings, which also work with conda's Graphviz package.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. I did find out about another fix though.

import os

os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH']+';'+os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX']+r"\Library\bin\graphviz"

Comment: Have you restarted your Karnel of  Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Yes, but that did not solve the problem. The code I mentioned in the comment above worked.

Comment: Great.. Not sure why, but the steps I have mentioned have worked for me.